# What is the address of local labels in NASM?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, memory-address

In `NASM` assembler, it's possible to declare local label using `.` prefix.

1. So, what is the address of local label (and label in all assemblers generally)? Is it relative or absolute, or it depends on use?

I'm asking because there are features that confuse me. This is an example code:

```
ORG 0x400000 ;origin of address for labels

start:       ;address here should be 0x400000
.....        ;some code here

     .loop   ;local label
     .....   ;some code here
     jmp short .loop ;<------- address is not taken as absolute
     jmp short start
```

If I take some normal label (like `start`) for referencing and I use it with `lea` instruction, address is calculated as normal absolute address with respect to origin.

2. But if I take label and I use it with `short` (as on the last line), what is happening? Is the offset for jump calculated from absolute address?

I'm asking all  this because I have local labels in my code (`.LNXYZ`, randomly generated), and I need to make list of addresses (from that labels) that will have 4-byte elements containing absolute address for jumps. Is such thing possible, or I have to use normal labels? Is there any directive for it?

Comment: You probably want `bits 32` at the top of this. Your origin seems a little high for 16-bit code (which is what Nasm will produce by default. `jmp label` uses relative addressing mode - the actual code emitted will be `jmp distance_to_label`. Shouldn't matter if the label is "local" or not. For an absolute jump, you'll have to do `mov eax, label` and then `jmp eax`. You shouldn't need to code `short` - Nasm should give you a `short` jump if it'll fit, and a `near` jump if it won't. I'm not sure I get the part about "randomly generated" labels...

Comment: So if I want list of 32-bit absolute values generated by NASM, what should I do?

Answer (score 6):

From [NASM user manual](https://cs.nyu.edu/courses/fall02/V22.0201-001/nasm_doc_html/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.9):

> **3.9 Local Labels**
>
> NASM gives special treatment to symbols beginning with a period. A
>   label beginning with a single period is treated as a local label,
>   which means that it is associated with the previous non-local label.
>   So, for example:
>
> ```
> label1  ; some code 
>
> .loop 
>     ; some more code 
>
>     jne     .loop 
>     ret 
>
> label2  ; some code 
>
> .loop 
>     ; some more code 
>
>     jne     .loop 
>     ret
> ```
>
> In the above code fragment, each JNE instruction jumps to the line immediately before it, because the two definitions of .loop
>   are kept separate by virtue of each being associated with the previous
>   non-local label.
>
> This form of local label handling is borrowed from the old Amiga
>   assembler DevPac; however, NASM goes one step further, in allowing
>   access to local labels from other parts of the code. This is achieved
>   by means of defining a local label in terms of the previous non-local
>   label: the first definition of .loop above is really defining a symbol
>   called label1.loop, and the second defines a symbol called
>   label2.loop. So, if you really needed to, you could write
>
> ```
> label3  ; some more code 
>         ; and some more 
>
>         jmp label1.loop
> ```

Comment: In the time I asked this, I didn't have enough information about assembler in general, so my question wasn't accurate. Actually, I was asking about how to get the absolute address of a label. That's what I can do by using the name of the label in a place where I need to have the address, and the NASM will manage everything else for me. I'd like to delete my question now, so if you could remove your answer, I'd do it.

Comment: if you want to get effective address of label, use assembly instruction `LEA`, this return effective address of memory (label) and save this in registry [LEA](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_153.html)

Comment: Or I just use the symbol name. Don't worry ( :)), I understand it now, and that's why I think this question is no longer needed.

Comment: This answer (and the question) are helpful and should not be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

The address of a local label in NASM is exactly the same as it would be if the label were not local.

The only thing that changes is that the label's name gets appended to the first previous non-local label.

Minimal example:

```
outside_label:

    ; This should be not done in practice,
    ; but shows how it works under the hood.
    jmp outside_label.inside_label
    ; This is not reached.
.inside_label:

    ; This is what you should do in practice.
    ; Labels also get appended when used as arguments.
    jmp .inside_label2
    ; This is not reached.
.inside_label2:
```